# WebAPI AuthorizeAttribute with Protobuf returns 500

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-web-api, protobuf-net

I have an issue that has been puzzling me for a while now. I've managed to reduce as much as I can.

I have a standard `System.Web.Http.ApiController` with a Get method that simply returns `Ok();`

The controller is marked with `[WindowsAuthorize]` which is a custom attribute of own creation. Currently, this attribute is reduced to this:

```
public class WindowsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, using Postman, when I make a `GET` request to my endpoint with the following header, I get:

```
Accept: application/json
//Status: 401, Body: { "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

Same request, but with the protobuf header:

Now, using Postman, when I make a `GET` request to my endpoint with the following header, I get:

```
Accept: application/x-protobuf
//Status: 500, Body: (empty)
```

Somehow, the `401` becomes a `500 Internal Server Error`, but I get no exceptions server side. Am I doing something obviously wrong here, or how can I debug this?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the correct behaviour is to return `401`, then the client should try again with NTLM auth enabled, right? (Assuming commented the full code back in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that whenever a body is sent - in this case `{ "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."}`, it needs to be protobuf serializable as well.

Comment: How did you achieve this?

Comment: @JakubHolovsky: It's been a while, but I believe we used 'well known types' to register an error type.